# 500 error on AJAX request to MVC controller method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How do I return a view to an AJAX call? Right now I do a get request with AJAX jQuery to my controller method, but it hits the `error` handler.

I have this dropdownlist in my view:

```
<select id="linkDocumentDropDown">
    <option value="ten">10</option>
    <option value="twentyfive">25</option>
    <option value="all">all result</option>
</select>
```

And this AJAX call to my controller that returns the view:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/SearchResult",
    type: "GET", 
    data: { 
        searchString: $("#SearchString").val(), 
        pageSize: 25 
    },
    complete: function (xData, status) {
        $("#test").html(xData);
    },
    error: function (status) {
        alert(status.message);
    }
})
```

And my controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SearchResult(string searchString, int pageSize)
{
    QuestionAnswerService service = new QuestionAnswerService();
    SearchedQuestionsResponse searchResults = new SearchedQuestionsResponse();
    bool isSufficientLength = false;
    string[] searchTerms = searchString.Split(' ');
    foreach (string term in searchTerms)
    {
        if (term.Trim().Length > 2)
        {
            isSufficientLength = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) && isSufficientLength)
    {
        searchResults = await service.GetSearchQuestions(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, searchString);
        Session["SearchResults"] = searchResults;

        if (searchResults.searchedquestions == null || searchResults.searchedquestions.Count == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.message = Messages.NoResults;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.searchtext = Messages.SearchResults + " " + searchString;
            Session["SearchText"] = Messages.SearchResults + " " + searchString;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.message = Messages.SearchStringInvalid;
    }

    //  int pageSize = PAGE_SIZE;
    int pageNumber = PAGE_INDEX;

    return View(searchResults.searchedquestions.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get? You should be able to see it in the console, as well as in the properties provided to the `error` handler. It's most likely a 500 error in the Action. If so, we would need to see more of your C# code to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks, yes i get 500 error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). Ok i updating my SearchResult Action method, see the code above

Comment: Can you give any more information on the error, such as what the exact detail is and what line it occurs on. Your code looks fairly straightforward, so I'd guess it's in the `GetSearchQuestions` method of your `QuestionAnswerService`.

Comment: I have debugged my action controller and it dosent throw any error, what can i do to debug it further?

Comment: But can i return a view with ajax like this?

Comment: Yes, it should work, although I would suggest returning a `PartialView` instead of a `View`.

Comment: Ok, i modified the SearchResult method (removed int pageSize), it works then, but the pagesize is the meaning with my function..